# Attach to WCF proceess, but break points don't get hit

Tags: wcf, debugging, iis, process

I've successfully attached to a WCF process for debugging but my VS2010 says that no executable code lies where the breakpoints are.
Its says possible reasons are compiler optimizations or conditional compilation.

What should I do next?

Comment: By default setting it to `Release` would optimize the code. If you change it to `Debug` and `Code Optimization` is not checked in you're project property pages it would work.

Comment: @Silvermind thanks, where is that “Optimize code” checkbox in Visual Studio. I can't find it in the prefs for the project

Comment: Right-click on your project and select 'Properties'. Go to tab 'Build'. There should be a checkbox 'Optimize code' under the 'General' section.

Comment: @Silvermind hmm.. I don't have a general section when I do that

Comment: It should be in the property pages of the 'WCF' project. Are you looking in that project?

Comment: Also make sure you include the PDB-files in the WCF publish.

Comment: Cool, please put it in an answer so you get the points!

Comment: Made it an answer. I assume you got it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, setting the project to `Release` would optimize the code, while `Debug`-mode is by default not optimized.
This can however be changed by setting the `Optimize code` checkbox to true in the property pages. Right click the project and select 'Properties', Than go to the 'Build' tab and under the 'General' section there should be the option to select/unselect `Optimize code`.

When you publish a project and want to make it 'debuggable' you should also include the pdb-files on the server. This would basically support for debugging WCF applications when debugging is enabled for the website in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a lot of times. Here you have a number of things to do:

- Recompile your code.
- Double check IIS configuration (Basic Settings/Physical Path) to get sure that is pointing to your code.
- Get sure *.pdb files are there.
- Get sure that you put your breakpoint as soon as possible, in the first line.